# How can I improve my knowledge on Underwater routing protocols using Unetstack?

Tags: routes, unetstack

I am new to Unetstack and the programming too.

I am in my first year of Ph.D and I would like to continue my research on Underwater Routing Protocols using Unetstack. I am following the Unet handbook but still facing alot of difficulties.

Please suggest me some docs and useful video lectures to improve my understanding on underwater routing protocols and further I would like to implement some new routing protocols for underwater networks.

Answer (score 0):

Much material on this topic exists in literature, and a good place to start in your Ph.D. is to do a thorough literature survey. A simple Google search for underwater routing protocol brings up several recent articles reviewing work in this area:

1. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5982538/
2. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11276-021-02880-z
3. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9312119
4. https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/55198

This might provide a good starting point to understand state of art, and then you can try implementing some of these using UnetStack.

Disclaimer: I have not read any of the above articles and am not endorsing the contents. I am simply pointing out that there is material available that you can start from. Your Ph.D. supervisor might be able to provide you better guidance.